# Google App Engine: DeadlineExceededException in dev

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is [`DeadlineExceededException`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/DeadlineExceededException.html) thrown in gae/j dev mode?

Comment: I'm just saying that someone *might* come along, look at the tags and the question, not realize their relevancy, go "WT*?", and downvote.  Those were my first thoughts before I realized what you were talking about.

Comment: Glad to help.  :-)  (you may want to spell out "Google App Engine" though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. You could write an [API call hook](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/App-Engine-Java-API-call-hooks) to throw one if you wanted, though.

Comment: It throws com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApiDeadlineExceededException in dev server for me.